# Multi-Monitor Slowdown

Tags: interface, customization

I have been trying to use my second monitor with blender without much success.

I have 2 windows and can move them around fine, but the moment i move any window off my main screen onto my second monitor the blender interface window on the second monitor lags like crazy. But on the main monitor it is fine. I can also have both windows on the main screen fine without and lag.

It is driving me mad and while not necessary for what i am doing it would make my life much easier if i could use both monitors.

Comment: Try  updating the drivers for your graphics card.

Comment: Performance will depend on the kind of GPU, the amount of vRAM and the size of your monitors.

Comment: Has cegaton as mention this is probably a graphics cards or driver issue. I currently use a dual monitor setup at home with Blender without any sort of problem, but I had a similar issue on an older work computer running Windows XP. What are your system specs, operating system graphics card? Pretty hard to lend any help without useful info.

Comment: Current i am using a GTX 980 with the v364.72 which are the current drivers. I am on Windows 10 with an i75960x and 64 gig of ram, blender is running off an ssd and saving onto an ssd.